# Creating a correct PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having difficulty looping to create a test array (before using similar approach to loop through a recordset). This PHP code does not work:-

```
$dataSet1 = array();
$dataSet1['label'] = 'Customer 1';

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
    $dataSet1['data'] = array($i,$i);
}

echo json_encode($dataSet1);
```

It only produces last value for data, not 3 data pairs:-

```
{"label":"Customer 1","data":[2,2]}
```

Where am I going wrong? I have googled, tried array_push, but no luck. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the *final* array to look like?

Comment: change $i < 3 to $i <= 3

Comment: You are *overwriting* the value of `$dataSet1['data']` with each iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: Why the negative marks? I thought Stackoverflow was to help fellow programmers, not punish newbies. I could have spent another hour googling & testing, after doing so for 45 minutes, but the answers here were very fast & saved that extra time. But thanks for the answer, it DID save considerable more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep overwriting the value for `$dataSet1['data']` in your loop.

If you want to append to an array, you can use this syntax:

```
$dataSet1['data'][] = array($i, $i);
```

Or, you can use the `array_push()` function:

```
array_push($dataSet['data'], array($i, $i));
```

Comment: Thanks, absolutely works, incredible that just '[]' makes all the difference. As you were first I will mark as answer. Could not get 2nd solution working, it gave {"label":"Customer 1","data":null} even though I changed $dataset to $dataset1.

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the value for the 'data' index every time you loop.

```
$dataSet1 = [];
$dataSet1['label'] = 'Customer 1';

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
    $dataSet1['data'][] = $i;
}

echo json_encode($dataSet1);
```

Comment: Thanks, this absolutely works. Unfortunately I can't mark 2 answers as correct. But thanks again for help.